# Can a user remove a flag that they have set?

Tags: support, flagging

Lets say a user posts a question. Another user, based on the questions content, thinks that the question belongs on another StackExchange site, such as WebApps, and flags it. Then the other user edits their question to clarify something which makes the question valid on SU. Can the second user remove his 'flag?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot, but if you leave a comment and/or second flag to invalidate your previous flag, we'll simply dismiss it for you.